# Modal focus highlight remains on element after closing modal window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-modal, pseudo-class

I have a modal set up, using Bootstrap, which is working just fine.  The modal brings up some text and an image.  When I hover on the modal element, a `button`,  there is a nice blue highlight that pops up, I'd like to keep that.  The issue is, when I close the modal window the blue highlight stays on the `button`,  I'd like to get rid of this.

I thought this CSS...

```
.modal-open .modal,
.btn:focus{
    outline: none !important;
}
```

...would remove the highlight, but it I'm still left with the blue highlight after I close the modal.  The following is the code for the modal...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img  src='http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200'></button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Some Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text about something, Some text about something, Some text about something.</p>
        <a href='http://codepen.io'><img  src='http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200'></a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I think you are looking for the pseudo class `:active` and not `:focus`

Comment: That's what I tried first, still have the highlight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
  $('#myModaltrigger').one('focus', function(e){$(this).blur();});
});
```

Comment: This would probably also work, but breaks accessibility

Answer (score 1):

This is by design and is important for accessibility. On close, modals should return focus to launching element. If the button wouldn't get it's focus back it would break keyboard/tabbed accessibility. Please refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12364).

If you want to remove the glow, or blue "highlight" i recommend toggling an extra CSS class on modal show/hide. For example:

```
<button id="openButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-no-highlight" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img src='http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200'></button>

$(function(){  
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#openButton').toggleClass('btn-no-highlight');
  });
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#openButton').toggleClass('btn-no-highlight');
  });
});

.btn.btn-no-highlight {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/e61r4ba3/